# Holding Down Button and window updating issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

When I keep holding down `Ctrl+Up`, I need that the label to update on intervals of 1000 ms. (If I hold `Ctrl+Up` down for 5,2 seconds, the commands should run 5 times.)

The `after` method does not seem to work on this. It also acts weird, as if it records how many times I pressed the key and keeps looping that even after `Ctrl+Up` is unpressed.

```
from Tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

def start(event):
    global x
    x = x+1
    x_var.set(x)
    root.after(1000, lambda: start(event))

x=1

x_var=IntVar()
x_var.set(x)

r = Label(root, textvariable=x_var)
r.pack()

root.bind('<Control-Up>', start)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to run a command every 1000 ms while holding <kbd>Control + Up</kbd>:

- Store and update the [current pressed statuses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181037/4084269) of <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Up</kbd>.
- Have an `.after()` loop which calls itself every 1000 ms, in which you run the desired command if both <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Up</kbd> are currently pressed.

**Code**

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

x = 1
x_var = tk.IntVar()
x_var.set(x)

r = tk.Label(root, textvariable=x_var)
r.pack()

isPressed = {"Control_L": False, "Up": False}

def update_key_status(key, value):
    global isPressed
    isPressed[key] = value

# Make the Press/Release events of both keys update the "isPressed" dictionary
for key in ["Up", "Control_L"]:
    root.bind('<KeyPress-{}>'.format(key), 
              lambda evt, key=key: update_key_status(key, True))
    root.bind('<KeyRelease-{}>'.format(key), 
              lambda evt, key=key: update_key_status(key, False))

def increment_x():
    global x, x_var
    x += 1
    x_var.set(x)

def start():
    if (isPressed["Control_L"] and isPressed["Up"]):
        increment_x()
    root.after(1000, start)

start()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh, that worked the way I wanted. I'm using python 2.7, forgot to say :x. I adjusted the Tk's and it worked, I'll study more about what you did there, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The after method does not seem to work on this.

No, it is working as your program asks it to do.

> It also acts weird, as if it records how many times I pressed the key
>   and keeps looping that even after Ctrl+Up is unpressed.

It is not that weird. Throw a glance to a given [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) and you will  read:

> The callback is only called once for each call to this method. To keep
>   calling the callback, **you need to reregister the callback inside**
>   **itself**

The bold text is  what you exactly did in the `start()` function. So the logic behavior with your current code is that, once you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Up</kbd>, that callback will wait 1000 milliseconds to be executed, and after that it will continue running forever (well, until you end the `mainloop()` event)

So to make your program increment the label's content only once after each press on the keys you specified, you need to avoid the design written in bold text above. A solution then could consist in creating a specific incrementalist function like this:

```
def increment_x():
   global x, x_var
   x += 1
   x_var.set(x)
```

Then use this function as a callback within your `start()` function:

```
def start(event):    
    root.after(1000, increment_x)
```

So your code becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import * 

root = Tk()    

def start(event):    
    root.after(1000, increment_x)

def increment_x():
   global x, x_var
   x += 1
   x_var.set(x)


x=1

x_var=IntVar()
x_var.set(x)

r = Label(root, textvariable=x_var)
r.pack()

root.bind('<Control-Up>', start)
root.mainloop()
```

P.S. Please follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Ok, but it still doesn't do what I want. The label is updating like 30 times per second when holding down the Control+Up. I want the commands to run once after 1 second, when holding down the Control+Up.

Comment: You must press down **once and release** the keys. Otherwise, if you keep pressing the keys (holding them down) you are triggering the event binding to execute, so the content of the label will increment fast and keep responding to the event @MaiconErick

Comment: So, there's no way to "pause" the execution for a while when holding down the keys to achieve what I want?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is against the philosophy of [events binding](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm). I hope you understand this. If you want to "break" this rule however, you can hack your program: for instance, check when the content of the label is changed to 2 and then use `unbind()` method to unbind the continuous key press event. But then do not expect an other key press will work. @MaiconErick

Comment: I want to have this kind of "wait" because under heavy work, let's say, if I keep holding down the keys for 5 seconds, the label will only update after 5 seconds.

Comment: I managed to get what I want by putting a `root.update()` between the functions when it starts struggling to update the Label in real time. Thanks for the help, guys.